# Assign python code to a jupyter notebook shortcut

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to extend the functionality of jupyter notebooks by assigning the run of some python code to a keyboard shortcut.

For instance, I would like to be able to select an array in a cell (highlighting its variable name), press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and obtain a plot of the array in a new cell. This would allow me to run the same block of code in a quicker way while I am writing some other code.

How is it possible to set this up?

Comment: Read this page of the documentation: [Keyboard Shortcut Customization — Jupyter Notebook 6.1.6 documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html)